# How to set spring dispatcherServlet path?

Tags: java, spring

I use *application.properties* file to set `DispatcherServlet` path:

```
server.servlet.path=/api/
```

When I go to url `/api/`, I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'servlet[path]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties]: Bean property 'servlet[path]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:731)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:948)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

How to set DispatcherServlet path?

Comment: The correct key is `server.servlet-path`, not `server.servlet.path`

Answer (score 1):

You always can look over [the Spring properties appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) to find a property you want:

```
server.servlet-path=/ # Path of the main dispatcher servlet.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the *application.properties* [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

> server.servlet-path=/ # Path of the main dispatcher servlet.

The correct key is `server.servlet-path`, notice the `-`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501351/how-to-configure-spring-viewresolver-to-resolve-to-thymeleaf-pages-or-to-jsp-pag

Answer (score 1):

It's `spring.mvc.servlet.path` now (2.3.x). Let's see when it changes again :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `spring.mvc.servlet.path=/api` since `server.servlet.path` got deprecated